# How to prove that a stock's price deviation from its moving average is a mean reversion process?

Tags: probability, statistics, time-series

If you build a moving average from stock price values, then the price graph fluctuates around this moving average.
How can one mathematically prove that a price's deviation from its moving average is a mean reversion process?

If $x_{t}$ - price at moment $t$,

Exponential Moving Average (EMA):
$y_{t}=(1-\alpha )\cdot y_{t-1} + \alpha \cdot x_{t};\ \ where\ \alpha = Const, 0 < \alpha < 1$

or
Simple Moving Average (SMA):
$y_{t}=\frac{1}{k}\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{k-1}x_{t-i}$

Price deviation from its moving average:
$s_{t}=y_{t}-x_{t}$

UPDATE:
While discussing with @Henry I realized the ambiguity of my question, because... I meant mean reversion as it is defined in finance:
**"Asset's price will tend to converge to the average price over time"**
So it is enough to prove that this process is autoregressive (AR(1) with autoregression coefficient $0 < \varphi < 1$), which is what I did in one of the drawings for an exponential moving average. But I haven’t succeeded yet with the proof for a simple moving average...

Comment: Why should it be? one can imagine processes that don't satisfy that.  What assumptions are you making?

Comment: We imagine that (a mathematically ideal) stock price process is a martingale so no trading strategy has non-zero expected value.  For instance, betting on mean reversion to the moving average should have zero expected value.  Of course, real world processes are not ideal.

Comment: @lulu Assuming that price increases are a normal process N(0,1).

Comment: @lulu My question is about the mathematical proof of the observed fact of price oscillation around its moving average. I understand that betting on this process has zero expected value.

Comment: But, again, observed processes are not mathematical objects.  There are lots of reasons a physical process might mean revert.  Markets overreact to news.  Perfectly understandable.  But that's not the case for a set of coin tosses.  At each point your expectation is the new average, not some trailing thing.  The mathematical process has no memory...has no idea what the moving average was.

Comment: Typo:  Meant to say "new level" not "new average".

Comment: Typo: Meant to say: "price changes are a normal process N(0,1)"

Answer (score 1):

This is not "mean reversion": the price changes are presumably independent of what has happened before and assumed to be a homogeneous Markov process so the price level is a random walk.

Knowing the current moving average and current price level tells you nothing about future price changes.

Instead, what happens is that the moving average of the recent past moves towards the current price level as more distant price levels (further from the current price level) fall out of the average and more recent price levels (close to the current price level) are included in the average.

Here is a simulation in R to illustrate this:

```
set.seed(2023)
changes <- rnorm(65,0,1)
plot(changes)
```

which shows the $N(0,1)$ price changes
[image]

Let's apply this to a starting level of $1000$ to give a time series of price level and then subtract the simple moving average of the $5$ most recent values.  It appears to oscillate around $0$, and thus might appear to suggest some kind of mean reversion:

```
level <- cumsum(c(1000,changes)) 
ma <- function(x, n){stats::filter(x, rep(1 / n, n), sides = 1)} 
simplema <- ma(level, 5) 
plot(level-simplema) 
abline(h=0)
```

[image]

But if you look below at the actual price levels (black) and the moving average (red), you can see it is the moving average which tends to move towards the price level rather than the other way round, particularly noticeable in this simulation between $40$ and $50$.

```
plot(level, type="b")
lines(simplema, col="red")
```

[image]

Comment: All your statements are correct, but they are not about the properties of the process I was asking about: 
**Price deviation from its moving average: s(t)=MA(x(t))−x(t)**

Comment: @RoustemAkhiarov and I am saying that if mechanism is that the moving average tends to moves towards the current price, with the consequential impact on $s(t)$, then this is not a "mean reversion" process

Comment: As I proved in my first answer to my question a few hours later,
values of s(t) follow the auto-regression equation and tend to hover around 0 and revert to the mean after regressing from it.
How will you call it if not "mean reversion"?

Comment: I would say the moving average tends to move towards the current price.

Comment: Henry,

I was confused with different definitions of Mean Reversion in math statistics and finance.
Agree with you, this process does not satisfy math statistics definition of the "mean reversion" for the reasons you already mentioned.

But it does satisfy definition of "mean reversion" in finance:
"Mean reversion is a financial term for the assumption that an asset's price will tend to converge to the average price over time."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reversion_(finance)

Comment: Henry, You said: 
`I would say the moving average tends to move towards the current price.`  
Let's forget for a moment how the time series was calculated (difference between price and it's MA) and look at it as a series of numbers.  
How will you call it's behavior ?

Answer (score 0):

Proved for EMA:

$$
s_{t}=y_{t}-x_{t}=\\
(1-\alpha )\cdot y_{t-1} + \alpha \cdot x_{t}-x_{t}=\\
(1-\alpha )\cdot s_{t-1} + (1-\alpha )\cdot x_{t-1}-(1-\alpha )\cdot x_{t}=\\
(1-\alpha )\cdot s_{t-1} - (1-\alpha )\cdot (x_{t}-x_{t-1})=\\
(1-\alpha )\cdot s_{t-1} - (1-\alpha )\cdot \epsilon_{t}\\
\\
\\
\\This\ is\ a\ formula\ for\ auto-regression\ AR(1)\ model,\ and\\ 
since\ (1-\alpha )<1\\ 
and\ assuming\ \epsilon_{t}=x_{t}-x_{t-1}\ is\ white\ noise,
\\
\Rightarrow s_{t}\ is\ \mathbf{mean\ reversion\ process}
$$